# A question about sequences of integrable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

Say $f_n$ is some sequence of Lebesgue integrable maps $[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ such that for all $x\in [0,1]$:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n (x) = 0$$

That is, the pointwise limit is the zero function.

Now consider the sequences

$$ \int_0^1 f_n(x)dx$$

and

$$ \int_0^1 |f_n(x)|dx$$

I believe that if the pointwise limit function is zero then these should also tend to zero but I'm not 100% sure.

Especially, I'm not sure how to argue it because they are only integrable and not necessarily continuous.

> Does anyone have any insights into this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, not true, even for everywhere pointwise convergence: Consider
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
n^2x & 0\leq x\leq 1/n\\
2n-n^2x & 1/n<x\leq 2/n\\
0 & x>2/n
\end{cases}.
$$
(Note that all $f_n$ are continuous…). Also look up Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to be sure: Am I right these $f_n$ look like triangles?

Comment: And the point is that the base of each triangle becomes gradually smaller while the height increases so that the non-zero value set of the $f_n$ gets smaller but the integral does not?

Comment: Correct two times!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I thought a bit more and now I think the real key point is that the triangles move to the left. If they were stationary the limit would not be the zero function. Am I correct?

Comment: Well, without movement, the counterexample would not work. But the real key-point is, that the sequence $f_n$ is not dominated by an integrable function, i.e. there is no integrable $g$ such that $|f_n|\leq g$ for all $n$. If the $f_n$ do not move, they overlap considerably more which makes it simpler for an integrable dominating function $g$ to exist.

Answer (score 1):

An easy counterexample in the case of almost everywhere convergence, since I've already written it. Dirk took care of the question better.

I also recommend to read something like this [Tao's post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/02/245a-notes-4-modes-of-convergence/)  about modes of convergence, to get a better idea of what's going on.

---

Take $f_n(x)=n\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}(x)$. Then $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere and 
$$
\int_0^1 |f_n(x)|\,dx=\int_0^1 f_n(x)\,dx=n\int_0^1 \chi_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}(x)\, dx= n \mu\left(\left[0,\frac{1}{n}\right]\right)=1,
$$ 
for any $n$ and where we denoted by $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. Here is a counterexample that $f_n(x)\to0$, but $\int_0^1 f_n(x)dx\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

Let $f_n(x)=n^2xe^{-nx^2}$ on $[0,1]$. Then for any $x\in[0,1]$
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n (x) = 0
$$
 But
$$
\int_0^1 f_n(x)dx=\frac{n}{2}(1-e^{-n})\to\infty
$$

Answer (score 0):

Or look at $f_n(x) = n^2x^n(1-x).$